# Does AspNetDB automatically reset Locked Out users?

Tags: aspnetdb

Does AspNetDB automatically reset Locked Out users?

I can't find anything saying it does... just looking for confirmation that I haven't missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't automatically unlock users. There is an UnlockUser method you can call, but you have to implement your own logic on when to unlock it.

```cs
public bool UnlockAccount(MembershipUser user)
{
    return user.UnlockUser();
}
```